# How to convert a List into a Map in Dart

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

I looking for an **on-the-shelf** way to convert a List into a Map in Dart.

In python for example you can do:

```
l= [ ('a',(1,2)), ('b',(2,3)), ('c',(3,4) ) ]
d=dict(l)
==> {'a': (1, 2), 'c': (3, 4), 'b': (2, 3)}
```

The dict function expects a List of couple. For each couple, the first element is used as the key and the second as the data.

In Dart I saw the following method for a List : **asMap()**, but it's not doing what i expect: it use the list index as key. 
My questions:

- Do you known anything in Dart libraries to do this ?
- If not, any plan to add such a feature in the core lib ?

Proposal:

```
List.toMap() //same as python dict.
List.toMap( (value) => [ value[0], value[1] ] ) //Using anonymous function to return a key and a value from a list item.
```

Thanks and Regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use [Map.fromIterable](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html):

```
var result = Map.fromIterable(l, key: (v) => v[0], value: (v) => v[1]);
```

or *collection-for* (starting from Dart 2.3):

```
var result = { for (var v in l) v[0]: v[1] };
```

Comment: `fromIterable` has very weak typing. So collection-for is the only recommended way.

Answer (score 69):

In Dart 1.1, you can use [this constructor](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Map.html#fromIterable) of Map:

```
new Map.fromIterable(list, key: (v) => v[0], value: (v) => v[1]);
```

This would be closest to your original proposal.

Comment: fromIterable has very weak typing. So collection-for from @Alexandre's answer is the only recommended way.

Answer (score 59):

#### For Dart 2.3 and more ,

There are many solutions, but the simplest are :

**1- Use the `asMap()` function**

```
List list = ['steve', 'bill', 'musk'];
Map map = list.asMap();
print(map);
```

**Output :**

```
{0: steve, 1: bill, 2: musk}
```

**2- Use `for-in` collection inside your map** `Map map = {};`

```
List list = ['steve', 'bill', 'musk'];
Map map = {for (var item in list) '$item' : 'valueOf$item'};
print(map);
```

**Output :**

```
{steve: valueOfsteve, bill: valueOfbill, musk: valueOfmusk}
```

Hope it will be helpful .

Comment: The 2nd soln worked for me. My use case was to convert a `List` of Strings into `Map<String, bool>`, which gave me the intended result. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Another possibility is to use the [`Map.fromEntries()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.fromEntries.html) constructor:

```dart
final result = Map.fromEntries(l.map((value) => MapEntry(value[0], value[1])));
```

Answer (score 4):

### Details

- Flutter 1.26.0-18.0.pre.106

### Solution

> /libs/extensions/list.dart

```
extension MapFromList<Element> on List<Element> {
  Map<Key, Element> toMap<Key>(
          MapEntry<Key, Element> Function(Element e) getEntry) =>
      Map.fromEntries(map(getEntry));

  Map<Key, Element> toMapWhereKey<Key>(Key Function(Element e) getKey) =>
      Map.fromEntries(map((e) => MapEntry(getKey(e), e)));
}
```

### Usage

```
import 'package:myApp/libs/extensions/list.dart';

final list = [1,2,3,4];
print(list.toMap((e) => MapEntry(e-1, e)));  // {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
print(list.toMapWhereKey((e) => "str $e"));  // {str 1: 1, str 2: 2, str 3: 3, str 4: 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may not directly relevant to the answer but, if there is anyone who wants to convert.

```
var list = ['fee','fi','fo','fum'];
```

to a Map like,

```
var map = {0:'fee', 1:'fi', 2:'fo', 3:'fum'};
```

you can use

```
var map = list.asMap();
```

**PS**

This map is not editable

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet a concept of tuples or pairs in dart (other than a two element Iterable).  If Dart had such a concept, then [issue 7088](http://dartbug.com/7088) proposes to solve this with a Map.fromPairs constructor.

Comment: +Alexandre solution even based on 2 element list is fine for me, it does the job. I use it for myself.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can convert list into map

```
void main() {
  var list = [99, 25, 45, 11, 5, 125, 50];
  SplayTreeMap numbers = new SplayTreeMap<int, int>();
  numbers.addAll(list.asMap());
  print(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = [Gum, 0.95, Soda, 1.05, Chips, 1.99];
Map map1 = {};
for (int i = 0; i < list.length ; i += 2) {
   map1[list[i]] = list[i + 1];  }
print(map1);
```

The output will be:

```
{Gum: 0.95, Soda: 1.05, Chips: 1.99}
```