# Different Datastructure Serialization between Client and Database

Tags: flutter, dart, serialization, google-cloud-firestore

Within my client I have a class, e.g., `ClassA` that contains a property `List<ClassB>`.

My goal is to save the object `ClassA` within Firestore. Also I want the `List<ClassB>` property saved into Firestore as a Map instead of an Array (also be able to save it as a `List<Object>` within the client).

Since I want to use the `json_serializable` library is there a way to specify for a given class' property how to get serialized/deserialized and choose what kind of a key should be used for the Firestore Map?

Comment: Why not just convert the List into a Map, and provide that to Firestore?

Comment: @DougStevenson This is what I am trying to do, but I am not sure how to with the json_serializable. I want to keep the List structure in my client though.

Comment: You don't have to abandon the list.  Just use it to compose a map for the purpose of writing to Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson right, so we are talking about the same thing :) My question is, if it is possible to do this semi-automatically using the library mentioned above instead of writing this manually.

Comment: As far as I can see, that library deals with JSON, not other objects Dart objects.  Firestore doesn't deal with JSON, it deals with Dart objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the answer to my question.

So in order to use the `json_serializable` for the remaining `ClassA` properties I have to use the `@JsonKey` annotation for the property `List<ClassB>`. By doing this, I can then use custom `fromJson/toJson` methods. In this methods I can transform `myList` to an appropriate Map for Firestore.

This is how I have to use it:

```
@JsonKey( fromJson: _firestoreMapToList, toJson: _listToFirestoreMap)
final List<ClassB> myList;
```

The methods `_firestoreMapToList` and `_listToFirestoreMap` will "override" the automatically generated methods of the `classA.g.dart` file, which is also automatically generated when using the `json_serializable` library and entering this `flutter pub run build_runner watch` in the terminal.

This is how the methods exactly look like:

```
static List<ClassB> _firestoreMapToList(Map<String, dynamic> firestoreMap) {
 if (firestoreMap != null) {
  return List<ClassB>.from(firestoreMap?.entries
      ?.map((e) => ClassB.fromJson(e.value))
      ?.toList());
 }
 return null;
}


static Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> _listToFirestoreMap(List<ClassB> list) {
 if (list != null) {
  return Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>.from(list?.asMap()?.map(
      (key, classB) => MapEntry(
          classB.firebaseId,
          classB.toJson())))
    ..removeWhere((key, value) => key == null); // remove map entries with null as key
 }
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a List to a Map you should not need to convert the object to JSON and then back.

You can use `Map.fromIterable()` or collection-for to convert a List to Map. See this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831806/12163274)

Comment: You are right in this case. Although this is not what I was trying to explain. I was talking about the different datastructures that I want to use in my database and my client. For this case I need a `toMap/fromMap` or `toJson/fromJson`. I did find the solution. It is also posted here now.