# Save list getting from JSON URL in firestore collection

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My small app, is getting list of users from JSON link then store it in the List, I wanna this list into `usersCollection` collection ref of firestore

[image: usersCollection]

my code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:yat_flutter_app/main.dart';
import 'usersList.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  CollectionReference usersCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bYKKPeXRcO?indent=2");
    var jasonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<User> users = [];

    for (var i in jasonData) {
      User user = User(i["index"], i["about"], i["name"], i["picture"],
          i["company"], i["email"]);
      users.add(user);
    }

    return users;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<User> usersList = getUsers() as List<User>;


    return Container(

      child: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: getUsers(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshop) {
              if (asyncSnapshop.hasData) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: asyncSnapshop.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          color: Colors.cyan[50],
                          child: ListTile(
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.share),
                            title: Text(asyncSnapshop.data[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Tahoma',fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  asyncSnapshop.data[index].picture +
                                      asyncSnapshop.data[index].index.toString() +
                                      ".jpg"),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(asyncSnapshop.data[index].email,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Tahmoma',fontSize: 18),),
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                                  detailsPage(asyncSnapshop.data[index])
                              ));
                            },

                            onLongPress: ()=>

                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                    msg: asyncSnapshop.data[index].name,
                                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16.0
                                ),

                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                );
              } else {
                return Text("Loading, please wait...");
              }
            },
          ),

          ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Save data'),
              onPressed: () => {
                
      usersCollection.add(getUsers()); // here's I am trying to add the result of getUsers into usersCollection 

              }),
        ],

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To push an object to Firestore you need to convert your `object` to `map`.
You can just add this function to your class:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'field1': value1,
      'field2': value1,
    };
  }
```

To push a List , you need to convert all objects to map, you can do it with following method:

```
  static List<Map> ConvertToMap({List myList }) {
    List<Map> steps = [];
    myList.forEach((var value) {
      Map step = value.toMap();
      steps.add(step);
    });
    return steps;
  }
```

Or simply , see **[how to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831535/how-to-convert-a-list-into-a-map-in-dart)**

I hope it will be useful

Comment: Thanks for explaining , I tried to getting the result of `getUsers();` method and put it into `ConvertToMap();` like this `List list = convertToMap(getUsers());` but it's not working, I think the problem is because the method is Future

Comment: I think you should turn the convertToMap function into an asynchronous function to do this

Comment: I tried to add `Future` to it but it's not valid `A value of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be returned from the method 'convertToMap' because it`
I'll waiting to for the solution how to convert the result of this future list to dynamic map list (your method)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase realtime database and firestore are no SQL databases where data will be stored in Parent child relation or Tree structure.

For you to store list of data you can convert your list into **Map**
Map can be initialised as follows

```
Map<String, String> toMap() {
  return {
    'Fruit': "Mango",
    'Flower': "Lotus",
    'Vegetable': "Potato",
  };
}
```

After you have Map you can set value to the firestore. You can use the below code to set value

```
Map<String, Object> city = new Map<>();
//Loop through your list and load Map (City) values
db.collection("cities").document("LA").set(city)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
    }
});
```

You can convert List of items to map using this

[Java: How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map/4138420)

Comment: Storing Map data is easiest. So convert your JSON list to a map or hashmap to make your work easy. If you have more doubts you can reach me out here.

Comment: first and third methods not valid with this case

Comment: @MML Ok, I have edited my answer to Map and setting map to firestore. Check it out if it works

Answer (score 1):

To push this list to Firestore you need to **fromJson** and **toJson** methods in your model class

```
 factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data){
    return User(
        index: data['index'] as int,
        about: data['about'] as String,
        name: data['name'] as String,
        picture: data['picture'] as String,
        company: data['company'] as String,
        email: data['email'] as String );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){

    return {
        "index": index,
        "about" : about,
        "name" : name,
        "picture" : picture,
        "company" : company,
        "email" : email,
    };
  }
```

instead that I would like to suggest using [**json_serializable**](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) library

then you need to do some changes in your future method like this

```
getUsers().then((users) {
// add users to map
});
```

and then you can use **fromJson** method to push it to firestore database