# How to convert list into map form and get result like this?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert a list into map form and get results like this:

```
{"data":[{"id_pet":"63","id_habit":0},{"id_pet":"64","id_habbit":0}]}
```

My code:

```
event.listPet.asMap();
```

My list:

```
↓   pet: List (2 items)
  ↓ [0]: Pet
    id_pet: 1
    id_habbit: 1
  ↓ [1]: Pet
    id_pet: 2
    id_habbit: 2
```

Comment: can you include your original list that you wanna convert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a List into a Map in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831535/how-to-convert-a-list-into-a-map-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

```dart
return {"data": event.listPet.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList(),};
```

You should make sure `toMap` method is defined in your Pet class.

Comment: "The method 'toMap' isn't defined for the type 'Pet'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toMap'.",

Comment: create one yourself. Or generate it from plugins.

Comment: i don't understand can you help more @rahul

Answer (score -1):

use `fromIterable`

```
Map<String, dynamic> map1 = {
    "id_pet":"63",
    "id_habit": 0
  };
  
   Map<String, dynamic> map2 = {
    "id_pet":"64",
    "id_habit": 0
  };
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [];
    
  list.add(map1);
  list.add(map2);
  
  var map3 = Map.fromIterable(list, key: (e) => "data", value: (e) => list);
  print(map3);
```

Comment: this data is taken from list not hardcoded @jungwon